# NativeScript Side Drawer unhooked page

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I'm new to NativeScript and I've been following the instructions [here](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/tns-template-drawer-navigation) to create my app.
However I find out that all pages are hooked to the drawer, how do I unhook some pages, such as Login, Create ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to the sidedrawer and disable the interaction.

```
import { getRootView } from "tns-core-modules/application";

this.drawer = <RadSideDrawer>getRootView();
this.drawer.gesturesEnabled = false;
```

The above is implemented in the login page of [this POC application](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/login/login.component.ts#L44-L45).